# How to express the Laplace in polar coordinates?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Hello I started learning PDEs and I can't solve one problem.

By using of polar coordinates $\left( r, \theta\right)$, where according to the usual calculus notations:
$$ r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \text{ , }\tan \left({\theta}\right) = \frac{y}{x} \text{ , }
x = r\cos\theta  \text{  ,  }   y =r \sin \theta$$

Show that
$$ u_{xx} + u_{yy} = u_{r r} + \frac{1}{r} u_r + \frac{1}{r^2} u_{\theta \theta} = 0$$

So at first I tried to calculate $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} $

$$  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u }{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} =  \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} - \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} = $$

$$ =  \cos \theta \frac{\partial u}{ \partial r} - \frac{\sin \theta}{r} \frac{\partial u}{ \partial \theta}$$

And I did similar thing for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ and got
$$  \frac{\partial u}{ \partial y} = \sin \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} + \cos \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}$$

Now I am trying to find $u_{x x}$ and $u_{y y}$ but I don't know how to use the chain rule in this situation can you give me a hint?

thanks in advance

Comment: Reformulate the post title with your true question: How to express the laplacian in polar coordinates? Otherwise people won't know what you ask for without clicking the post.

Comment: Solved it! don't waste your time anymore <3